# How to echo else on if(isset($_SESSION

Tags: php

I'm trying to do this thing.

If user is not logged, it will show him

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X4nq.png  this image as avatar. + login ahref

If user has session, it will show him Skins row.  + logout ahref.

But when I'm doing "else" it shows me weird layout.

```
<?php
    session_start(); //starting session 
    include("config.php"); //including our config.php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 


    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //if session is set, so if user is logged in... 
    { 
        $username = $_SESSION['username']; //setting variable username as one from session 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //looping thousgt table to get informations 
        { 
            $Skin = $row['Skin'];
        }
    } else 
        echo "  <li class='second admin-pic'>
                       <ul class='top_dp_agile'>
                                    <li class='dropdown profile_details_drop'>
                                        <a href='' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>
                                            <div class='profile_img'>   
                                                <span class='prfil-img'><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X4nq.png' alt=''> </span> 
                                            </div>  
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class='dropdown-menu drp-mnu'>
                                            <li> <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-cog'></i> Log IN</a> </li> 
                                            <li> <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-user'</i> Make new Account</a> </li> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                        </ul>
                </li>";
?>
```

and this is html

```
<li class="second admin-pic">
                       <ul class="top_dp_agile">
                                    <li class="dropdown profile_details_drop">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <div class="profile_img">   
                                                <span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/<?php echo $Skins ?>.jpg" alt=""> </span> 
                                            </div>  
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu drp-mnu">
                                            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Logout</a> </li> 
                                            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Forum</a> </li> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                        </ul>
                </li>
```

Shall I define $skins if is >1 (avatars will be named numeric) to show html and then instead of that HTML just to replace it with echo $skins ?

What I want to remove HTML for good and replace it just with echo, ex.

```
    if($Skins    > '0') {
    $Skins = "<li class='second admin-pic'>
                       <ul class='top_dp_agile'>
                                    <li class='dropdown profile_details_drop'>
                                        <a href="#" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>
                                            <div class='profile_img'>   
                                                <span class='prfil-img'><img src='images/<?php echo $Skins ?>.jpg' alt=''> </span> 
                                            </div>  
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class='dropdown-menu drp-mnu'>
                                            <li> <a href=''><i class='fa fa-cog'></i> Logout</a> </li> 
                                            <li> <a href=''><i class='fa fa-user'></i> Forum</a> </li> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                        </ul>
                </li>";}
```

and html

```
// another divs, etc.

?php echo $Skins ?>

new divs
```

is this good way ? because now it's showing exactly this way

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2iyf.png

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Eyes tinks days just wantz dah codez mon man. ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner actually I want to learn by practicing, but mysql looks easier (because I'm just practicing in it maybe, but I started to learn mysqli too on w3schools)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.